# How to Initialize Different Kotlin Data Classes That Follow the Same Procedure?

Tags: android, oop, design-patterns, kotlin, software-design

I have a bunch of models in my app, which are data classes. Through my app (which is a media player) I follow pretty much the same routine for getting instances of these classes.I want to query the database(which here is the MediaStore) using a projection for Songs/Albums/Artists, and I want to create instances and append those in a list, which will serve as my library.

What I have done so far in order to create a list of Songs is as followed:

```
val SONG_SEARCH_PROJ = hashMapOf<String, String>(
"id" to MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns._ID,
"title" to MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
"album" to MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM,
"album id" to MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM_ID,
"artist" to MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST,
"artist id" to MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST_ID,
"data" to MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA)



var songLibrary: () -> ArrayList<SongModel> = {
    var songsList = ArrayList<SongModel>()
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        uri,
        SONG_SEARCH_PROJ.values.toTypedArray(), selection, null, sortOrder
    )
    cursor?.let { current_cursor ->
        while (!current_cursor.isAfterLast) {
            SONG_SEARCH_PROJ.apply {
                songsList.add(
                    SongModel(
                        current_cursor.getData("id", this).toInt(),
                        current_cursor.getData("title", this),
                        current_cursor.getData("data", this),
                        current_cursor.getData("artist", this),
                        current_cursor.getData("album", this),
                        null
                    )
                )
            }
            current_cursor.moveToNext()
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    songsList
}
```

Also for better readability, I have created an extension function for the `Cursor` class, which gets a hashmap, and a string which will serve as the key.

```
fun Cursor.getData(key: String, hashmap: HashMap<String, String>): String{
    return this.getString(this.getColumnIndex(hashmap[key]))
}
```

My data classes are also as followed:

```
@Entity
data class SongModel(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val Location: String,
    val ArtistName: String,
    val AlbumName: String,
    val ArtWorkLocation:String?)
```

======

```
data class AlbumModel(@PrimaryKey val name: String, val artistName: String, val songList: ArrayList<SongModel>)
```

======

```
data class ArtistModel(@PrimaryKey val Name: String, var albumList: ArrayList<AlbumModel>)
```

=====

My problem is at the moment, I can't generify the "createLibraryOf_X_Model" function, since Kotlin does not accept creating instance of generic types. I have also stumbled upon factory pattern, but I had a hard time adjusting it to my current problem.

Edit: I have not exactly explained my problem here that well, so I'm rewording the above paragraph.

My current problem is that, give that the logic of queries over database and creating instances are pretty much the same, it's fairly logical to expect to somehow generfiy the "Library Generation" function, which will result in me passing the model class and the query parameters to the function, and it will create the library accordingly. What I do currently is that I have a different generation method for each of my libraries, and the only difference between them is the selection arguments on the MediaStore queries on call on the constructor of the class in order to create new instances.

Comment: @tynn I'm planning to, but I'm still very early into the development, and have not used Room in the app. Just defined these entities as Room entities for the future.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what's your actual issue. Could you state your question more clearly?

Comment: @tynn I'm trying to get rid of duplicate functions. Currently I have SongLibrary property, which creates a cursor on the MediaStore database and generates the instances of my songmodels, but going forward, I will have to do the same for also my AlbumModels, and my ArtistModels. I want to somehow generify this process, and avoid writing duplicate logic of queries and all for different models.